# how to highlight json difference in php or js

Tags: javascript, php, json, compare, difference

I have two json data:

```
$old_data = '{"stock_id":"583",
              "stock_date":"2017-03-11",
              "stock_quantity_in":"0",
              "stock_note":"moved to warehouse A}';

$new_data = '{"stock_id":"583",
              "stock_date":"2017-03-11",
              "stock_quantity_in":"3",
              "stock_note":"moved to warehouse B}';
```

how do I compare them and highlight the differences? Using php or js are welcome

[UPDATE] I think this [one](http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/diff-implementation/) is the closest one I need, thanks!

Comment: php would be server side, meaning a POST (page refresh) would be required vs JavaScript

Comment: i think this one is the most close one i need : http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/diff-implementation/#styling, thanks!